# Set Regarding field of email activity in a workflow to the Primary entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Is there a way to set the "Regarding" field for an email in a Send Email activity in a workflow to the Primary entity of the workflow?

I tried using the Form Assistant but it won't let me bind the primary entity of the workflow to the 
Regarding field of the email message.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like Activities aren't enabled for the entity.  Go to the entity configuration screen and check.  When I use a Send Email step for an entity that has Activities enabled, it defaults the Regarding field to the primary entity.